# Piping input parameters to openssl

Tags: batch-file, scripting, openssl

I have a bash script that I am trying to port to Windows. It takes an input string and passes it via `stdin` to `openssl` to create a `hmac`.

How would I port this?

```
echo -n $BUILD | "$OPENSSL" dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:$SECRET | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

*BUILD comes from an input parameter to the script. It seems that -mac and -macopt are not valid options on the Windows binary. The script should display the hmac on the console.

Comment: Did you tried anything before asking? I can't see you effort or batch code

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a batch version of the indicated script (of course, openssl is still required)

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "BUILD=something"
    set "SECRET=0102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f"
    set "OPENSSL=x:\somewhere\openssl.exe"

    for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('
        ^<nul set /p ".=%BUILD%"
        ^| "%OPENSSL%" dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:%SECRET%
    ') do echo %%a
```

- In batch, variables are assigned values using `set` and their values are not retrieved using `$VAR` syntax but `%VAR%`
- In batch the `echo` command will always include a CR+LF end of line, the `-n` option does not exist. In can be replicated (with limitations) using a `<nul set /p` command.
- If you have a windows binary for `awk` you can keep the same pipe used in your original code, but with double quotes, not single quotes. The proposed code uses the `for /f` command to read the output of the `set /p | openssl` pipe and retrieve the second token in the line (by default delimiters are spaces and tabs)
- The redirection and pipe characters need to be escaped when used inside the `in` clause of a `for /f` command, the reason for the `^<` and `^|`

**note**: tested with openssl 1.0.2g (what I had at hand) and the `-mac` and `-macopt` arguments work without problems.